# While sending base64 image to server in ajax post "/" are getting gconverted to '%'

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, base64, image-uploading

I want to upload an image as base64 to server. So I am sending request like this

```
$.post(Config.serviceURL('captureImage/' + memid), {
    imageString: imageData
}, function(data) {
    alert("Image uploaded!", data);
}).fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

The imageData parametre contains the base64 string. Now the problem is that whenever I am sending request to server all '/' in the base64 are getting convetered to "%" I don't know why is it happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the problem really, but you could decode64 imageString on the server to get the slashes back to normal "/".